# Why is my custom TestCase class not being found when running tests through PhpUnit?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, phpunit, autoload

I added PHPUnit to my Symfony project as described in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html). Creating and running the first test which extend `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase` was no problem.

Now I would like to create a custom `WebTestCase` subclass which provides common features for other test classes:

```
// .../projectDir/tests/BaseTestCase.php
namespace My\Project\Tests;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class BaseTestCase extends WebTestCase {
    protected function doSomething() {}
}


// .../projectDir/tests/SomeTest.php
namespace My\Project\Tests;

use My\Project\Tests\BaseTestCase;

class SomeTest extends BaseTestCase {
    protected function testSomething() {
        $this->doSomething();
        ...
    }
}
```

When running `php bin/phpunit` I get an "Class not found" error:

```
$ php bin/phpunit
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'My\Project\Tests\BaseTestCase' not found in /path/to/projectDir/tests/SomeTest.php:6
Stack trace:
#0 /path/to/projectDir/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/FileLoader.php(65): include_once()
#1 /path/to/projectDir/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/FileLoader.php(49): PHPUnit\Util\FileLoader::load('/path/to/...')
#2 /path/to/projectDir/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(402): PHPUnit\Util\FileLoader::checkAndLoad('/path/to/...')
#3 /path/to/projectDir/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(530): PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->addTestFile('/path/to/...')
#4 /path/to/projectDir/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestSuiteMapper.php(67): PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->addTestFiles(Array)
#5 /path/to/proje in /kunden/100170_47877/webpages/pockey/webpage/dev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php on line 98
```

I have double checked the class name, the namespace and `use` statement (which should not be necessary, since both classes are in the same folder/namespace).

Do I need to register `BaseTestCase` in `PHPUnit` somehow to be a valid superclass for my tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are missing the declaration of the class paths for your test directory.

Generally, for the test classes themselves it's not necessary, since PhpUnit will load the test files and read the classes directly. But any other class referenced in any of the tests will need to go through the autoloader. And if you haven't declared where to find the `Test` namespace, it will try to find it with your regular project files (e.g. in `src/`).

Add an `autoload-dev` key to your `composer.json`. E.g., something like this:

```json
{
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "My\\Project\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "My\\Project\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  }
}
```

Dump the autloader after this (`composer dump-autload`), and try running your tests again.

Comment: Note that there is a tiny typo in the dump command, it should be `composer dump-autoload`.